# Custom Converter // Cast from or to?

Tags: java, casting, converters

In a project im using a lot of classes, that are generic and using the type definition `<? extends Comparable>`. Since `Boolean` is not comparable, but i'd like to use this classes with Boolean values, too, I created my own `ComparableBoolean` which looks like this:

(I wrote a comparable proxy class for Boolean, because it is final)

```
public class ComparableBoolean extends Object implements Serializable, Comparable<ComparableBoolean>{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
static Boolean FALSE = Boolean.FALSE;
static Boolean TRUE = Boolean.TRUE;

private Boolean booleanObject;

protected Boolean getBooleanObject(){
    return this.booleanObject;
}

public ComparableBoolean(boolean value){
    this.booleanObject = new Boolean(value);
}

public ComparableBoolean(String s){
    this.booleanObject = new Boolean(s);
}

/**
 * Will return 0, when both Booleans are equal, -1 else.
 */
@Override
public int compareTo(ComparableBoolean another) {
    if (this.getBooleanObject() == another.getBooleanObject()){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}   

//Functions derived from final class Boolean
/* A Lot of Proxy functions mapping x() to Boolean.x()
}
```

This works so far, and even knowing, that a Boolean can not be smaller or larger than another Boolean, this meets my requirements.

But now, i'm facing the problem that i "sometimes" need to cast a "ComparableBoolen" to a "Boolean" or vice versa.

Now i'm wondering if theres the possibility of defining custom "casts".

My investigations showed, that there might be the possibility to define own casts, like (in my Case):

```
public static implicit operator Boolean (ComparableBoolen cb)  
{ 
   return cb.getBooleanObject();
}
```

and

```
public static explicit operator ComparableBoolean(Boolean b) 
{
    return new ComparableBoolean(b);
}
```

All this - so google said :P - needs to placed into a CustomConverter... But i neither can find this class nor does (Android) the sdk know what "implicit / explicit or operator means...

What i am trying to achieve:

```
Boolean b = new Boolean(true);
ComparableBoolean cb = new ComparableBoolean(true);

b = cb; //No Invalid class cast exception here :)
cb = b; //and none here.
```

edit: Google cheated on my: implicit / explicit are examples from c# :P - are there equivalents in Java?

Comment: For a simpler approach, is it feasible to do something along the lines of cb.asBoolean() and ComparableBoolean.fromBoolean(b)?

It doesn't solve the casting problem, but easily lets you go back and forth between the two.

Comment: Who said [Boolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) was't comparable?

Comment: Just use Boolean, it is comparable and boolean is converted to it automatically if needed - it's called autoboxing. Java has no implicit conversions, but if you're adventurous enough, you can look at Scala that has them:)

Comment: @Perception You are right... It now is :) One should look into the new APIs more often. (I faced a similar Problem times ago, and there i learned, that http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html Boolean is NOT Comparable :P Okay, than this thread is basically obsolete ;)

Comment: @dognose - Ah, I see. You were looking at some old documentation. Generics weren't introduced until Java 5, so you wont find Comparable<T> or any of those other lovely interfaces in the 1.4 docs. Good luck with the project.

Comment: @Perception i didn't actually look into it, i just remembered that Boolean is not Comparable. (so why should I look into the API for *Boolean*? - now I know why i should check back from time to time :P )

Answer (score 0):

Define 2 methods:

```
public static ComparableBoolean valueOf ( Boolean b )
{
   if ( b.booleanValue( ) )
   {
     return TRUE;
   }
   return FALSE;
}

public Boolean booleanValue ( )
{
  return booleanObject;
}

Boolean b = cb.booleanValue( );
ComparableBoolean cb = ComparableBoolean.valueOf( b );
```

This is consistent with primitive to object conversion pattern in Java